# openssl encrypted file cannot be decrypted by others

Tags: openssl

This is on OS X. I encrypted a file using command below:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in secrets.json -out secrets.json.enc
```

I was required input a password.
Then I can decrypt it with

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in secrets.json.enc -out secrets.json
```

I was asked to input password and I used the one that I set up just now. The decryption is successful.

However, my colleague copied this file and just found that he cannot decrypt it with the same command and password. Here's what he saw:

```
10:59 $ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in secrets.json.enc -out secrets.json
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
4611925440:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:570:
```

My OS X has

```
11:31 $ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

His OS X has

```
11:29 $ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
```

Later he upgraded to LibreSSL 2.9.2 but still seeing the same.

Comment: Just to make sure the file didn't get modified in transit, run this command on each Mac: `md5 secrets.json.enc`  Is the output the same on both machines?

Comment: @JimL.: I'm pretty sure that it's not. Because I asked him to send it back to me and I can decrypt it.

Comment: same between a mac and linux mint, but without salt, and error ends with `evp_enc.c:536`, which only means another version of the code

Comment: I just found that I have two versions of openssl on my machine. Running command with path solved this issue.

Answer (score 14):

Probably a bit late, but I had the same issue and figured it out: it is because by default LibreSSL and OpenSSL don't use the same digest to create the key from the passphrase. LibreSSL uses MD5 and OpenSSL sha256. You can ask to use a specific one with `-md` option either when encoding or decoding. Using

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in secrets.json.enc -out secrets.json -md md5
```

on the OpenSSL version (the one you used to decrypt) should have worked.
In any case it is better to specify this during encryption as well to avoid relying on versions default settings.

Comment: For future readers, just want to stress that you shouldn't use `md5` as it's unsafe, use `-md sha512` on the LibreSSL end when encrypting instead.

Comment: For me, the "other" person is my future self. When future self tried to decrypt a file with the same command and password as past self, I got the same error as the OP. My past self didn't specify an `-md` option, and apparently the default setting was `md5`. Apparently [an upgrade from ~1.0.2 to ~1.1.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER3) changed the default message digest. Adding `-md md5` to my decryption command worked.